# getting specific part from a page source python

Tags: python, json, regex

I am trying to extract a specific part from a page using regex but it isn't working.

This is the part I want to be extracted from the page:

```
{"clickTrackingParams":"CPcBEJhNIhMIwrDVo4qw3gIVTBnVCh28iAtzKPgd","commandMetadata":{"webCommandMetadata":{"url":"/service_ajax","sendPost":true}},"performCommentActionEndpoint":{"action":"CAUQAhoaVWd4MEdWUGNadTdvclcwT09WdDRBYUFCQWcqC1pNZlAzaERwdjlBMAA4AEoVMTA1MTc3MTgyMDc5MDg5MzQ1ODM4UACKAVQSC1pNZlAzaERwdjlBMixlaHBWWjNnd1IxWlFZMXAxTjI5eVZ6QlBUMVowTkVGaFFVSkJadyUzRCUzRMABAMgBAOABAaICDSj___________8BQAA%3D","clientActions":[{"updateCommentVoteAction":{"voteCount":{"accessibility":{"accessibilityData":{"label":"80 likes"}},"simpleText":"80"},"voteStatus":"LIKE"}}]}}
```

So far I've tried this :

```
import requests
import re


r = requests.get('http://rophoto.es/ash.txt')
html_source = r.text

mystrx = re.search(r'^{"clickTrackingParams".*"voteStatus":"LIKE"}}]}}', html_source)
```

but it didn't work out for me.

Comment: tried [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)? unless you have restrictions on packages, BS would work pretty well with parsing web pages

Comment: There are lot of data matches your pattern available in the web page given. That may be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('http://rophoto.es/ash.txt')
html_source = r.text

fst, snd = '{"clickTrackingParams":', '"voteStatus":"LIKE"}}]}}'

# Find first occurence
end = html_source.find(snd)

# Get closest index
start = max(idx.start() for idx in re.finditer(fst, html_source) if idx.start() < end)

print(html_source[start:end+len(snd)])
```

Which Outputs:

```
{"clickTrackingParams":"CPcBEJhNIhMIwrDVo4qw3gIVTBnVCh28iAtzKPgd","commandMetadata":{"webCommandMetadata":{"url":"/service_ajax","sendPost":true}},"performCommentActionEndpoint":{"action":"CAUQAhoaVWd4MEdWUGNadTdvclcwT09WdDRBYUFCQWcqC1pNZlAzaERwdjlBMAA4AEoVMTA1MTc3MTgyMDc5MDg5MzQ1ODM4UACKAVQSC1pNZlAzaERwdjlBMixlaHBWWjNnd1IxWlFZMXAxTjI5eVZ6QlBUMVowTkVGaFFVSkJadyUzRCUzRMABAMgBAOABAaICDSj___________8BQAA%3D","clientActions":[{"updateCommentVoteAction":{"voteCount":{"accessibility":{"accessibilityData":{"label":"80 likes"}},"simpleText":"80"},"voteStatus":"LIKE"}}]}}
```

If you want to get the second occurence, you can try something along the lines of:

```
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('http://rophoto.es/ash.txt')
html_source = r.text

fst, snd = '{"clickTrackingParams":', '"voteStatus":"LIKE"}}]}}'

def find_nth(string, to_find, n):
    """
    Finds nth match from string
    """

    # find all occurences
    matches = [idx.start() for idx in re.finditer(to_find, string)]

    # return nth match
    return matches[n]

# finds second match
end = find_nth(html_source, snd, 1)

# Gets closest index to end
start = max(idx.start() for idx in re.finditer(fst, html_source) if idx.start() < end)

print(html_source[start:end+len(snd)])
```

**Note:** In the second example you can run into `IndexError`'s if you request an occurence outside of the found matches. You will need to handle this behaviour yourself.

Comment: clicktrackingparams value is not static its dynamically generated

Comment: @elrichbachman There are `368` occurences of `{"clickTrackingParams"` and `10` occurences of `"voteStatus":"LIKE"}}]}}` in the file.....I'm not sure how you can extract this specific segment?

Comment: from those 10 occurences of "voteStatus":"LIKE"}}]}} i want to get the first one which is mentioned in my question  :( i need help man :( if not regex , json could be used aswell i guess ,

Comment: thanks worked like a charm and got what i wanted also if you can edit and explain the code that'd be awesome :) thank you so much god bless u

Comment: Hey @roadrunner how can i get the second one from those  10 occurences ? 
your code gets the first one , how can i get the second one if i want ? thanks

Comment: @elrichbachman Have a look at my second example. You can create you own function to get the nth occurence. If your finding all this helpful, I would also appreciate if you upvote my answer also.